# Node.js compila o JavaScript que roda no servidor?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Segundo a documentação do V8, ele compila o JavaScript para código de máquina, como estratégia de otimização.

Dessa forma, o JavaScript que roda no servidor via Node.js é compilado ou interpretado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo fato do NodeJS utilizar a engine Javascript V8, seu código é compilado na hora para *bytecode* da máquina virtual V8. Antes dessa compilação, ele resolve os `imports` de módulos e otimiza a lógica do código.

Você pode comparar o NodeJS a um servidor PHP, Python, Java ou ASP.NET: O código é otimizado e compilado para uma linguagem de montagem intermediária (chamada *bytecode* -- similar ao *assembly*).

Vale lembrar que mesmo que o NodeJS e as outras linguagens tenham acesso a algumas funções da máquina ou do sistema operacional, quem executa este código compilado é a máquina virtual/interpretador da linguagem. Ou seja: por padrão Java usa a JVM (Java Virtual Machine), PHP utiliza o interpretador PHP baseado na Zend Engine, Python utiliza o interpretador Python da sua distribuição (Jython, IronPython, CPython, PyPy) e o ASP.NET utiliza a CLR do .NET Framework.

Answer (score 2):

É interpretado e, em seguida, compilado "on the fly" JIT com o V8.

Ao contrário de Java, que compila o código em bytes e, em seguida, o código de é compilado para algo que a máquina pode entender, NodeJS permanece JavaScript e, em seguida, o JavaScript é compilado em "tempo de execução".

Referência: https://hashnode.com/post/is-nodejs-compiled-or-interpreted-language-cijylh0ed00keco5318e1em8p